# Looking for a game engine to make a game like "Ikariam" or "Ogame"

Tags: c++, 2d, game-design, architecture, multiplayer

I'm an IT student and currently in my spare time I want to start a project. I would like to make a game that resembles a browser games like "Ikariam" or "OGame". I don't want this game to be a browser game, but It has to work like the games above with a couple of players.

What game engine would you suggest?

Comment: Any that you feel comfortable coding with. Can be done in any as long as your skills are good enough. We do not give software recommodations here. If you encounter a specific problem while implementing your game, feel free to post your problem and your tried approach with your code and error.

Comment: Sorry, but we generally don't give technology recommendations. What technology stack to use for what project is a decision based on the skillset and preferences of you and your team.

Comment: Are you still interested? I wanna join you and I have the experience and skills

Answer (score -3, accepted):

Technically speaking, it’s all a matter of personal preference. Nearly all game engines have the ability to create the games you listed above. But, here’s a list of some of the engines best suited for what you want:

1. **Godot** is an open source game engine that anyone can modify. It can compile games for nearly all devices. It is coded in *GDScript*, a Python like programming language.
2. **Unreal Engine** is a free game engine created by Epic Games. It can also  compile games for most devices. It uses *C++* as the main programming language, and is commonly used for online games.
3. **Unity** is a game engine that is licensed in three different ways: Free, Plus, and Pro. The free version includes most, but not all features of the others, such as watermark removal. But, it is one of the most powerful and easy to use engines, that can create games for basically every device. It uses *C#* as the main language.

There are many other different game engines, but this is just a list of my preferred programs.

Comment: [Please don't answer questions asking for technology recommendations.](https://gamedev.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/695/are-what-should-i-use-to-do-x-questions-really-on-topic-and-good)

Comment: Up to you. There's not much harm in leaving it here, though it might attract down-votes, in case that bothers you. If you let it draw one more then delete it, you could earn a badge. 

Comment: Please avoid answering questions you know are off topic. It's fine to help the user in comments on the question.

Comment: @noobprogrammer If you do decide you want to delete this, could you let me know first so I could downvote it and earn Critic? That way, we could trade badges.

Comment: Oh, I see. Well, nothing's gained by further downvotes, so I'll just stay on the prowl for someone else under peer pressure... >:)